# how to send an event to backend when using popup in Google Chrome extension develop

Tags: javascript

Now I am using a href to send a get request and append the request parameter into url to backend server like this in Google Chrome extension:

```
${config.submitto.feedly ? `<a href="http://122.96.19.223:11014/post/sub/source/temp/add?url=${encodeURI(url)}&userId=7" class="rss-action rss-submitto-feedly">订阅到 Cruise</a>` : ''}
```

now I want to submit a post request to backend server, I want to trigger a click event and append the user token info to server. The username and password was store in chrome.storage. what should I do to trigger a click event in popup menu in Google Chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

do it like this, change the UI code like this:

```
${
   config.submitto.feedly ? `<input type="submit" value="添加" class="rss-action rss-submitto-feedly"></input>` : ''
 }
```

then in js file trigger click like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((e)=>{
                        e.addEventListener('click',(innerEvent) =>{
                            innerEvent.preventDefault();
                           

                        });
                    });
```

the `<a></a>` also works fine for this purpose.